# Web Scraping with Beautiful Soup for Content of Specific Text within a Specific Tag

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-3.5

I am using bs4 in Python to scrape the web content by looking for a specific text within a general tag. Specifically:

html

```
...
<h3>Content</h3>
<ul>...</ul>
...
```

So, is there anyway I can instruct the bs4 to look for the  heading with specific text "Content" so that I can identify the anchor and to get the  content?

I have tried this but it did not work:

```
soup2.find('h3', {'text': 'Content'}).findNext('ul').text)
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [string filter](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-string):

```
soup.find('h3', string='Content')
```

The simplest filter is a string. Pass a string to a search method and Beautiful Soup will perform a **match** against that exact string.

This will be **full match**, if you want to find the tag **contains** this string, 
use regex filter:

```
soup.find('h3', re.compile=('Content'))
```

Comment: @CL. L palese accept my answer to close this question.

Comment: done, by the way, could you fix a typo of the compile function?